# Youtube Video Added in Product Gallery - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.2, media, product-video

I am getting error when i am trying to add Youtube link in product media gallery. Youtube API is already added. But still i am getting error. can you please describe me, How to i can fix this error ? Please below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Youtube does not give you 10,000 Queries a day, they give you 10,000 units a day; a query can be multiple units, depending on what you're doing:

- A simple read operation that only retrieves the ID of each returned resource has a cost of approximately 1 unit.
- A write operation has a cost of approximately 50 units.
- A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units.

More Information: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

I hope it is clear now.